# Connect R and Teradata using JDBC

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc, rjdbc

I´m trying to connect R and Teradata using RJDBC.

I´ve found this [link](http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/) that has an example using mysql, but i´m nos sure how to do the same with teradata.

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
           "/etc/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar",
           identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "user", "pwd")
```

I´ve downloaded this driver: 
http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver
But i´m not sure where i should reference the directory.

I know there is a teradataR package [out there](https://github.com/nonsleepr/teradataR), but i don´t know if it really works with the R 3.0.0.

For the time being i´m just interesting in pulling data out of the database. Something as simple as `SELECT * FROM table`. The problem is RODBC is very slow...

Are there other options for doing this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the R Console, enter the following steps below to make a Teradata connection:

```
drv = JDBC("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver","ClasspathForTeradataJDBCDriverFiles")
```

Example:

```
drv = JDBC("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver","c:\\terajdbc\\terajdbc4.jar;c:\\terajdbc\\tdgssconfig.jar")
```

NOTE: A path on a UNIX machine would use single forward slashes to separate its components and a colon between files.

```
conn = dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:teradata://DatabaseServerName/ParameterName=Value","User","Password")
```

Example:

```
conn = dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:teradata://jdbc1410ek1.labs.teradata.com/TMODE=ANSI,LOGMECH=LDAP","guestldap","passLDAP01")
```

NOTE: Connection parameters are optional. The first ParameterName is separated from the DatabaseServerName by a forward slash character.

```
dbGetQuery(conn,"SQLquery")
```

Example:

```
dbGetQuery(conn,"select ldap from dbc.sessioninfov where sessionno=session")
```