# Writing a data frame to a Teradata table using RJDBC

Tags: r, teradata, rjdbc

After establishing a connection as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998653/connect-r-and-teradata-using-jdbc/21017891#21017891), I tried to write a very simple data frame (`trythis`, shown below) to a table called `gh_test_20141105` in a database called `p_cia_t`. First, I tried

```
> conn <- getTdConnection(vdm='vivaldi')
> dbWriteTable(conn=conn,name=tbl,value=trythis)
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(s, "Unable to execute JDBC prepared statement ",  : 
  Unable to execute JDBC prepared statement INSERT INTO p_cia_t.gh_test_20141005 VALUES(?,?,?,?) ([Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.)
```

Next, I created an empty table in Teradata:

`create table p_cia_t.gh_test_20141105 (eenie integer, meenie integer, minie integer, moe integer);`

My next two attempts to write this data frame failed in contradictory ways:

```
    > dbWriteTable(conn=conn,name=tbl,value=trythis,append=T)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 3803] [SQLState 42S01] Table 'gh_test_20141105' already exists.)
> dbWriteTable(conn=conn,name=tbl,value=trythis,append=T,overwrite=F)
Error in .local(conn, name, value, ...) : 
  Cannot append to a non-existing table `p_cia_t.gh_test_20141105'
> trythis
  eenie meenie minie moe
1     1      4     7  10
2     2      5     8  11
3     3      6     9  12
> conn
An object of class "JDBCConnection"
Slot "jc":
[1] "Java-Object{com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection@2f242b11}"

Slot "identifier.quote":
[1] NA

> tbl
[1] "p_cia_t.gh_test_20141105"
```

Why would `append=T` object that a table already exists, and how can adding `overwrite=F` change the objection to "non-existing table?" Neither makes any sense.

I would greatly appreciate any working example of successful writing of a data frame to a Teradata table, whether pre-existing or not, with or without appending.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RJDBC_0.2-4      rJava_0.9-6      DBI_0.3.1        dplyr_0.3.0.2    scales_0.2.4     ggplot2_1.0.0    reshape2_1.4    
[8] RODBC_1.3-10     data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   chron_2.3-45     colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.2       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.0.1  
 [8] MASS_7.3-35      munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.2   plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.3      stringr_0.6.2   
[15] tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is due to a bug in Teradata's JDBC driver. As explained [here](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-java/2013/6/10951.html), the reason is that

> The problem is that in dbWriteTable RJDBC disables autocommit (and
> enables it again at the end), creates the table and then tries to
> insert into it in the same transaction. Firebird does not allow
> inserts into a table that is created in the same transaction.

[This page](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/ulrich/2013/11/a-wider-test-case-on-r-jdbc-fastload) seems to offer a solution but I think fundamentally we may have to wait until TD fixes the bug...

My temporary solution is to turn to ODBC (small table) or call fastload directly by `system(“fastload < your_fastload_script”)`  (big table)…